# how can I make a nested foreach with child foreach is base in parent id in knockoutjs?

Tags: knockout.js

This is the sample html:

```
<div class="order" data-bind="foreach:Orders">
<input type="checkbox" id="order"><h3 class="merchant_name" data-bind="text:MerchantName"></h3>
    <hr>
    <!--ko foreach:Details(param here base in parent id)-->
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#">
            <img alt="img" data-bind="attr: {src:Image}" />
        </a>
        <p class="hide"><a href="#" data-bind="click:$parent.RemoveOrder"></a></p>
        <p class="edit tm-modal"><a href="#edititem_1" data-bind="click:$parent.EditOrder"></a></p>
        <div class="details">
            <h3 class="product_title" data-bind="text:Title"></h3>
            <span class="price">
                <p class="original_price" data-bind="text:SubTotal"></p>
                <p class="now_price" data-bind="text:SubTotal"></p>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/ko-->
</div>
```

I wanted to make the child loop dependent in parent id. 
any Ideas and suggest to help solve this problem thanks,

Comment: can you show Orders Array structure?

Comment: did you try nested container less bindings <!--ko foreach:Details(param here base in parent id)--><!--ko if: parentId === 1--> <!--/ko--> <!--/ko-->